# PHP XML add edit delete

Tags: php, xml

I have the following XML structure, and I would like to have code that:

**INSERTS**

**DELETES**
Delete an entire element based on its TITLE value.

Replace the publisher's value with another value

```
<Game type="XXX">
<TITLE>XXX</TITLE>
<PUBLISHER>XXX</PUBLISHER>
</Game>
```

**This is my XML structure:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding ="utf-8"?>
<GameStore>
    <Game type="adventure">
        <TITLE>Assassin's Creed: Brotherhood</TITLE>
        <PUBLISHER>Ubisoft</PUBLISHER>
    </Game>

    <Game type="adventure">
        <TITLE>Batman: Arkham Asylum</TITLE>
        <PUBLISHER>Eidos</PUBLISHER>
    </Game>
</GameStore>
```

Comment: The first one is SimpleXML. The second one is DOM. Both only show the relevant parts to remove the node. They do not contain the setup code. Judging by your previous questions, you know how to instantiate a DOMDocument or a SimpleXmlElement. So what is your question? What is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to learn http://www.php.net/manual/fr/book.dom.php for manipulating xml.

There is some hints :

```
// Inserts
$new_node = $dom->createElement('foo', 'bar');
$gamestore_node = $xpath->query('/*')->item(0)->appendChild($new_node);
echo $dom->saveXML();

// Delete based on title
$deletable_node = $xpath->query("//Game[TITLE/text() = 'Batman: Arkham Asylum']")->item(0);
$deletable_node->parentNode->removeChild($deletable_node);
echo $dom->saveXML();

// EDIT Replace Publisher's value with another value
$editable_node = $xpath->query("//PUBLISHER[text() = 'Ubisoft']")->item(0);
$editable_node->nodeValue = 'baz';
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Answer (score 3):

Using SimpleXML:

```
<?php
// load the XML file
$games = simplexml_load_file('games.xml');
$i = 0;
foreach ($games as $game) {
    if ($game->TITLE == 'Batman: Arkham Asylum') {
        // remove the Game element
        unset($games->Game[$i]);
    }
    $i++;
}
// save the amended file
$games->asXML('games2.xml');
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use the PHP DOM classes. I think it goes something like this.

To load an XML file.

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load('path/to/file.xml');
```

To insert.

```
$node = $xml->createElement('Game');
$newnode = $xml->appendChild($node);
```

To delete based on title.

```
foreach ($xml->Game as $node) {
    if ($node->TITLE->nodeValue == 'some_title') {
        $xml->removeChild($node);
    }
}
```

etc

more info at http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php